# Call methods from a class that is inside an array

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I have an array with objects inside. How would I use methods on the array element?

My array is of type `Object`. I tried `array[i].getSalary()` but this doesn't work.

Comment: You could cast it but I beg you not to. Don't make your array of type Object, make it generic.

Comment: +1.  The solution is to make your array _not_ of type `Object[]` but of type `Employee[]` or whatever.

Comment: I understand but our professor requires it be of type Object.

Comment: Then you an only call a method like _getSalary()_ after casting, which is a **HORRIBLE** approach.  Perhaps you've misunderstood your professor and can use any object that is not primitive.  For example, if you have a class named _Employee_, then all instances of _Employee_ are Objects.

Comment: Your professor doesn't understand Java very well...

Comment: Am I the only one who has to downcast and catch UnsupportedOperationException  in production code?

Comment: @jahroy There's a chance that their professor is forcing them to use the horrible version first just to show them the elegant version afterwards and let them understand its value by hands-on comparison. I'm not saying this is what's happening, I'm saying it's a possibility.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis - That occurred to me... and I hope it's the case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First of all**, you should almost never use an array of `Object`. The reason is that you lose all type information that :

- would make the code more understandable for people who will read your code (including your professor, yourself, and yourself in six months when you will have forgotten everything about the code)
- could be used by the compiler and your IDE to tell you when you are doing mistakes even before you test the program.
- would avoid the type of error-prone casting that I am going to explain to you in the second part of this answer.

Instead of an array of `Object`, use an array of the type corresponding to the types of the object that will be put inside it (or a common base class). Assuming that your class is called `Employee`, you should declare your array this way:

```
Employee[] employeeArray;
```

(`employeeArray` is a better name than `array` because it tells what kind of objects it contains, again for readability. In general, prefer explicit names for variables.)

With that solution it is easy to use `employeeArray[i].getSalary()`, if the class `Employee` contains such method. The intention of this code is also obvious when you read it.

Other possibilities are generic collections like `List<Employee>` or `Set<Employee>`, depending on your needs.

**If you really have to use an array of Object**, and call a `getSalary()` method, you will have to *cast* the array elements to the class or interface to which the method `getSalary()` belongs.

For example and again, if this class is called `Employee`:

```
Employee employee = (Employee) array[i];
employee.getSalary();
```

What *casting* does is obtaining a reference of type Employee of your object. The object is still the same but now you can call methods of `Employee` on this object.

But this solution have a number of caveats. First, it is more verbose and it takes two lines to make what could have taken just one. Second, and more importantly, since you have an array of `Object`, you can not be certain that you really have an object of type `Employee`, and if it is not the case, the operation will throw a `ClassCastException`. A solution to this is to first check that the object is really of the desired type:

```
Object object = array[i];
if (object instanceof Employee) {
    Employee employee = (Employee) object;
    employee.getSalary();
}
else {
    System.err.println("Object is not an Employee: we can not call getSalary()!");
}
```

But you see that it becomes much more verbose and if you multiply this by the number of times you will have to call a method of these objects, then the code becomes unmanageable.

Comment: I expected a user with >2000 rep to suggest a better solution involving generics and not a poor one, for the very least you should explain the problems with this sort of solution or having an array of type Object. OP can use an array of types other than employee and it would still work using generics.

Comment: I understand what you mean but firstly, since this advice was already given in the comments, I felt it was not necessary to repeat right away. Secondly, even if the premisces of the OP's problem are bad, his question still shows a lack of knowledge regarding casting, so I don't consider a bad thing to show him that such a thing is possible. But thanks for your comment, I am going to amend my answer.

Comment: The problem is not OP specifically, other people will see this answer and learn a bad practice. Explicit casting is something that should be avoided whenever possible, it introduces problems in run-time that could have been caught in compile time negating the benefits of java being strongly typed. It also makes no sense logically, "see that object I told you was of type 'Object' ? well I lied, it's actually an 'Employee'". This sort of question is exactly when an explanation of java generics would come handy to help OP learn and future users in the same situation.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum I completely agree with you that the OP should learn why this is a terrible approach in Java. However, if his professor requires the array to be of type Object, then Cyrille Karmann did give the correct answer. I'm not saying it should be done like this, it's a terrible use of Java, but I don't see a better way given that he has to use an Object array.

Comment: @sage88 in that case the answer should say 'you should do this and that (make the array of type Employee, use generics with <? extends Employee> and other ideas), in the rare case that you can't do this properly you can cast as a last resort but it will have the following problems'. The problem is that this question will be read by people later and they will learn a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for fixing your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Do all your objects inside your `object[]` have the `getSalary()` method?

- If not, then you can obviously see why the compiler doesn't let you do that. There's something funny going on somewhere in your code if you end up in this situation.
- If yes, is it either the very same `getSalary()` method or multiple dynamically bound implementations of the same method in the same class hierarchy?

  - If neither, you should probably make an interface `IHasSalary` (lame name, I know) that exposes such a method, make all these objects implement that interface, then declare the array as `IHasSalary[]`.
  - If yes, find their most specialized common ancestor, say it's the class `Employee`, and declare the array as `Employee[]`.

Comment: Nothing is going on oddly. The class Object doesn't have the method getSalary(). It has to be cast in order to have the appropriate methods. I agree that it would be better practice to make an Employee array though.

Comment: @sage88 What I mean in that sentence is that something is wrong with the structuring/logic of the code. Meaning that if you *end up* with an `object[]` of objects that you know to be of some more specialized type, you've done something strange somewhere.